# Why is fread and fwrite giving error 'containing too many arguments'?

Tags: c, csv, fwrite, fread

I am working on a project in which data from .bin file have to be transferred to .csv . The data consists of many points each containing 4 values in varying dataformats, them being Time stamp, Pressure, System state and Alarm state.

Unfortunately the same error, being 'too many arguments to function', shows up for every instance of fread and fwrite and I can't manage to find a solution.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() 
{
    char temp;
    int size;
    int i;
    
    
    struct data
    {
        long long Time_stamp;
        int Pressure_pa;
        char System_state;
        char Alarm_state;
    };
    
    struct data data_t;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("pressureSpike.bin", "rb");
    
    FILE *csv;
    csv = fopen("pressureSpike.csv", "w+");
    
    if (fp== NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Data file would not open");
            return(-1);
        }
    
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size=ftell(fp);
    fprintf(stdout, "The size of the file is %d\n", size);
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_CUR);
    
    for (i = 0; i<= feof(fp); i++)
        {
            fread(&data_t, 8, 4, 1, 1, fp);
    
        printf("Time_stamp is %lld,  Pressure is %i in pa, System_state is %c, Alarm_state is %c\n", data_t.Time_stamp, data_t.Pressure_pa);
        
            fwrite(&data_t.Time_stamp, 8, 4, 1, 1, csv);
            fwrite(&data_t.Pressure_pa, 8, 4, 1, 1, csv);
            fwrite(&data_t.System_state, 8, 4, 1, 1, csv);
            fwrite(&data_t.Alarm_state, 8, 4, 1, 1, csv);
    }
    
fclose(fp);
fclose(csv);
fprintf(stdout, "Done reading files\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `fread()` and `fwrite()`, but I'd review their documentation: [fread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread); [fwrite](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite)

Comment: The answer is, … because you’re passing too many arguments. What do you expect to happen? What do you think these arguments correspond to? What is their purpose?

Comment: Besides the extra arguments, there are other things that don't make sense such as `i<= feof(fp)`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. OP didn’t tag the question at all. The [tag:c++] tag came from a suggested edit that should have been rejected.

Comment: `.csv` format and `fwrite` are not a good match. You might want to use a formatted output function like fprintf instead. OTOH `fread` *can* be used to read a binary file, provided the `struct` is chosen correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you're passing too many arguments to `fread` and `fwrite`.  The declaration of these functions is as follows:

```
   size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);

   size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

The first argument is the address of the object you want to write to, the second is the size of the object, the third is the number of those objects, and the fourth is the `FILE` stream to read from or write to.

In your case, you're attempting to read and write the contents of a single `struct data` instance.  So the size should be `sizeof(struct data)` and the number of elements should be 1.

Also, you don't want to use `feof`, as it doesn't detect an EOF condition until *after* you're attempted to read.  Instead, check the return value of `fread` to see if you've read something.

```
int rval = fread(&data_t, sizeof data_t , 1, fp);
while (rval < sizeof data_t) {
{
    printf("Time_stamp is %lld,  Pressure is %i in pa, System_state is %c, "
           "Alarm_state is %c\n", data_t.Time_stamp, data_t.Pressure_pa);
    
    fwrite(&data_t, sizeof data_t, 1, csv);
    rval = fread(&data_t, sizeof data_t, 1, fp);
}
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph Makes sense.  Done.